# Bootstrap Hamburger Menu Hidden & Mobile Isn't Collapsed by default

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have tried many different versions of bootstrap 3 but the problem still persists. The bootstrap menu works fine except on the iPad. On the iPad the hamburger menu is missing and the mobile menu is expanded by default. I have been searching for an answer to this for a long time, and can't seem to figure it out. It works on other iOS devices even using the same version of Safari 7.0. Has anybody come across this issue?

Comment: you got some code for us to look at?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0ba9bc5d93c1d1b5a228
Thanks!

Comment: Your gist does not have any bootstrap navbar code.